# Read encrypted Windows partition using Linux

Tags: linux, windows, veracrypt

I run linux debian, usually i'd be able to mount the windows partition and read/write data on it, now I encrypted Windows 10 with veracrypt, and it's no longer there.

My linux distro is already LUKS encrypted.

How do I open windows from linux now?

Answer (score 0):

#### I encrypted Windows 10 with veracrypt, and it's no longer there.

You need to install veracrypt for Linux.

> VeraCrypt can be [downloaded](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Downloads) from the official website. It's just
>   a tar file that you will need to extract it on your hard drive.
>
> After you have downloaded the .tar.gz file from the official website,
>   extract it somewhere on your hard disk. You can install it through
>   terminal and gui both. If you want to install VeraCrypt through
>   Terminal then use the console file otherwise use gui files. In this
>   article I will be installing using GUI file.
>
> **Open Terminal**
>
> First of all open terminal and cd into the extracted VeraCrypt
>   directory.
>
> [image: Open terminal to install veracrypt]
>
> **Execute Setup**
>
> Start the setup using the below command:
>
> ```
> $ sudo bash veracrypt-1.17-setup-gui-x64
> ```
>
> Your filename may be different if you're using different VeraCrypt
>   version.
>
> Now you should see the GUI setup to install VeraCrypt.
>
> Click 'Install VeraCrypt':
>
> [image: Install veracrypt in linux through GUI]
>
> Accept VeraCrypt terms and conditions:
>
> [image: accept veracrypt terms & conditions]
>
> Start the installation:
>
> [image: Veracrypt installation starts]
>
> The installation will begin in a separate console. It takes few
>   seconds to finish. Enter to exit the console after installation.
>
> [image: VeraCrypt installation begins]
>
> Now VeraCrypt is installed.

Source [How To Install & Use VeraCrypt In Linux An Alternative To TrueCrypt [COMPLETE TUTORIAL] - LinuxAndUbuntu - Linux News | FOSS Reviews | Linux Tutorials HowTo](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/encrypt-data-in-linux-with-veracrypt-an-alternative-to-truecrypt)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, my linux distro is already LUKS encrypted.. Does that make a difference? What to do after installing veracrypt?

Comment: @MyWays No idea. Please update your question.